# How can I cause `ls -l` output to be comma-separated?

Tags: shell, unix

I have a scenario where in unix, when you are listing all files in a directory, output is whitespace-separated. How can I get comma-separated output instead?

...so, instead of `ls -l` returning (as it presently does)

```
drwxr--rw- 1 shravan.usersgroup 290 DEC 21 10:00 sample.txt
drwxr--rw- 1 shravan.usersgroup 150 DEC 21 10:00 demo.txt
```

...how can I get the following?

```
drwxr--rw- ,1, shravan.usersgroup ,290, DEC 21 ,10:00 ,sample.txt
drwxr--rw- ,1, shravan.usersgroup ,150 ,DEC 21 ,10:00 ,demo.txt
```

Comment: It's not good practice to use `ls` programatically *at all*. If you use `find -printf`, you can specify any format string you want, including one with commas, as described in [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: More immediately, with respect to asking a well-received question -- all-caps is understood by many native English speakers to represent yelling, which is rude; and a title should be descriptive enough that someone knows what your question *is* (not just what it's about) by reading it. I've tried to edit to remediate those faults.

Comment: (BTW, for general questions about using UNIX tools, our sister site [unix.se] is often more appropriate; StackOverflow is specific to questions "unique to software development").

Answer (score 10):

EDIT: After reading below comments.

Try below thing,

```
ls --format=commas
```

It should work for you!

> This will print the file name with comma separated.

You need to modify your logic little bit if you want to get the file permission and other params as well.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'm glad that it works!
Please accept the answer so that others can get benefit in the future!

Comment: This would produce incorrect output if the filename contains a space.

Comment: @user1934428 Thank you for suggesting the good solution. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Great!
It works fine for me. I just wanted the list of file names with comma separated.

Answer (score 3):

On systems with GNU `find`, the following generates output with only commas (no spaces) between fields:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '%M,%n,%u.%g,%s,%Ax,%AX,%p\n'
```

One can also generate comma-separated descriptions of files and their metadata using GNU `stat`:

```
stat -c '%A,%h,%U.%G,%s,%y,%n' *
```

See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and [How can I get a file's permissions (and other metadata) without parsing `ls -l` output?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/087)

Answer (score 1):

To list the contents of a directory in Bash and output the list as comma-separated values, you can use the following command:

```
ls -m
```

The `-m` option tells the `ls` command to separate the output with commas.